# SSH login Script

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, putty

I am writing a script where i need to check  login credentials of all servers.
It should verify with password as well. I am using below logic but it fails with breaking the while loop when it success condition

```
 While read line

    do

    "C:/Programfiles/putty/plink.exe" - batch -pw "password" user@$line exit 10

    var = $(echo "$?")

    If [ $var =="10"]; then
    echo "success"
    else
    echo "fail"
    fi
    done < serverlist.txt
```

Whenever user credentials are success as because of exit command it coming out of while loop as still servers need to check. Please help me on this

Comment: Fyi:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Changed the code as standard

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't tell it to break. Your success condition is missing the `break` command.

```
while ...; do
    ...
    if [ "$var" = "10" ]; then
        echo "success"
        break
   else
        echo "fail"
   fi
done
```

Also your `var = $(echo "$?")` is doubly redundant. You'll get the same result with `var=$?`.

(Really you could even check `$?` directly, as in `[ $? = 10 ]`.)

Comment: I just added a break command keeping all same. Still same issue

Comment: Please some one help me on this